# Is there a faster way to determine if a port is open?

Tags: python, sockets, port

I have the following python code which works fine when the remote server is listening on the port. However if the destination is not reachable it takes ~20 seconds for the exception to be thrown.

Is there a way I can speed this up?

Could someone explain why it takes so long to trigger an exception if the timeout is set to 2?

```
 def is_host_reachable(ipaddress,port):
    try:
        s = socket.create_connection((ipaddress, port), 2)
        return True
    except socket.error as exc:
        print("Caught exception socket.error : %s" % exc)
        return False
```

Thanks.

Comment: Probably scrpit waits for timeout, you should be able to shorten it with https://docs.python.org/2/library/socket.html#socket.socket.settimeout

Comment: [`socket.create_connection()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/socket.html#socket.create_connection) tries to do a lot of things. Perhaps it would be faster to use the lower-level [`socket.connect()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/socket.html#socket.socket.connect) function instead.